# How to get one row per hour?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table containing one row for about every 2 minutes. The table has two columns (id and timestamp).

My question is: how do I get only the first row for each hour?

For example:

```
2015-07-12 14:01:23
2015-07-12 15:02:20
2015-07-12 16:03:53
2015-07-12 17:02:45
```

and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `join`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(timestamp) as mints
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY DATE(timestamp), HOUR(timestamp)
     ) tt
     ON t.timestamp = tt.mints;
```

If you assume that the id increments with the timestamp, then only one aggregation is necessary:

```
      SELECT MIN(timestamp) as timestamp, MIN(id) as id
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY DATE(timestamp), HOUR(timestamp);
```

However, this depends on the assumption that the id increments with the time.  And, you cannot readily fetch other columns from the table (if there were any).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT MIN(timestamp)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp), HOUR(timestamp)
```

This will select the minimum `timestamp` per hour. If you also want the `id` column as well, then you can use the above query as a derived table and join back to the original table.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bc92/2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called `mytable`, you could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE ORDER BY ID, TIMESTAMP) AS TBL GROUP BY ID;
```

Hope this helps.